# HTTP status 404 not found after requesting http://localhost:4080/testAPI/rest/hello

Tags: java, spring, servlets

Below is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>testAPI</display-name>
  
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>testAPI</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>test</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>testAPI</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My class file looks as below:

```
package testAPI;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello()
    {
        String resource="<? xml version='1.0' ?>" + "<hello> hello from XML</hello>";
        return resource;
    }
    /*@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String sayHelloJSON()
    {
        String resource=null;
        return resource;
    }*/

}
```

My version of java is 8, tomcat 7 and jersey 2.25. I have created a dynamic web project. When i access http://localhost:4080/ - tomcat homepage opens. http://localhost:4080/testAPI/ will show the index.html. However when i try accessing http://localhost:4080/testAPI/rest/hello- i get http status 404 not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your param value in web.xml needs to point to the package containing your class.

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>test</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

should be

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>testAPI</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped